# Combinatorial explanation of ${n\choose r}={n-1\choose r-1}+{n-1\choose r}$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-explanation, binomial-coefficients, solution-verification, combinatorial-proofs

${n\choose r}={n-1\choose r-1}+{n-1\choose r}$ (4.1)

Equation（4.1）may be proved analytically or by the following combinatorial argument：Consider a group of $n$ objects, and fix attention on some particular one of these objects-call it object 1. Now there are ${n-1\choose r-1}$groups of size $r$ that contain object 1（since each such group is formed by selecting $r- 1$ from the remaining $n-1$ objects).Also,there are ${n-1\choose r}$groups of size$r$that do not contain object 1. As there is a total of ${n\choose r}$ groups of size $r$,Equation（4.1）follows.

Here's why I feel it is so wrong. Nothing to say about first statement of proof. ${n-1\choose r-1}$ groups of "size $r$ " is in the explanation so I assume it is saying that each group has $r$ object but this is totally wrong since it is $n-1$ choose $r-1$ so it should have size of $r-1$ and why taking ${n-1\choose r-1}$ and saying this group contain the object one. I am sure $n$ is the decision maker of if obj-1 exist or not having $r-1$ does nothing. $n-1$ as I know may or may not have obj-1 because you may have choose the obj-1 and remove it from $n$. ${n-1\choose r}$ so how does changing from $r-1$ to $r$ effects that obj-1 is in that group or not? This explanation is so unnecessary and unclear. I was thinking what size is he talking about. So can anyone say If I am right or wrong? And explain me what actually is being said in human language which is really understandable?

Comment: If anyone have any question about question let me know!

Comment: Have you written out the list of subsets for a small example like $n=6, k=3$ ? When an abstract argument is confusing, a good first step is to see what happens with simple specific example rather than wrestling with the abstract proof right away.

Comment: @Ned Thanks for tips. I have done what you said but I did it in infinite way from start which was my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have $n$ objects. Consider groups of $r$ objects selected from those $n$. They may or may not contain Object $1$. Consider the set containing all objects but Object $1$. It has size $n-1$. So select $r-1$ objects from that set of $n-1$ objects different from Object$1$. You get ${n-1\choose r-1}$ groups of $r-1$ objects all different from Object$1$. Put Object$1$ inside each of them and you'll find the total number of groups of objects of size $r$, containing Object$1$. Now compute the number of groups of objects of size $r$, which do not contain Object $1$. You have a total number of $n-1$ objects (because you don't want Object$1$ to lie among them) and you have to form groups of objects of size $r$, hence that number is ${n-1\choose r}$

Comment: I excluded Object$1$ because it is "fixed", you already know it is gonna be an element of each size $r$-group of objects containing Object$1$, so I said: fix it, and see what happens for the others $r-1$ elements of such groups. Adding Object $1$ to them does not affect their number.

Comment: Yes, since Object1 is inside all groups of objects counted by first summand, you don't need to consider Object$1$ in that computation, you just consider all the other $r-1$ elements, and you count how many they are, and you find that that number equals the number of ways you can choose $r-1$ objects out of $n-1$, so you kind have to separate the two concepts: how many objects are there (they are $r-1$+ Object$1$, hence $r$ objects) from how many ways you have to choose them.

Answer (score 2):

The count for ways to select any $r$ from $n$ objects is: of course, $\tbinom{n}{r}$.

We can count this partitioned on whether you include a particular object or not. First we can count ways to select one from one particular object and $r-1$ from the $n-1$ other objects. Secondly we can count ways to select *none* from one particular object and $r$ from the $n-1$ remaining objects. The sum of these is the count of ways to select $r$ from $n$ objects. $$\binom{n}{r}~=~\binom{1}{1}\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{1}{0}\binom{n-1}{r}$$

Since in each term the first factor equals one, this simplifies.

$$\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{r}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are right and wrong.
The first group term does indeed denote choosing $r-1$ objects out of $n-1$, since you are excluding the object you are focusing on (Object $1$).
The second term denotes choosing objects with the Object $1$ deliberately excluded.
Thus, only $n-1$ objects are there, but we can have to choose an $r$-set out of them.
In total: $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r-1}+\binom{n-1}{r}$